# Convert JSON Parse Array to CSV

Tags: php, javascript, json, csv, d3.js

First Of all I saw The Other Threads and i think non of them is using PHP or javascript.

well i have this array after i encoded and added Slashes to escape the JSON illegal Characters:

```
"#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-12"  "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-19" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-19" "#Tahrir","2012-Oct-19"
```

want to change that to a CSV or find a way to use this with that Graph from this Sample: http://bl.ocks.org/3883245#data.tsv

Thanks Inadvance.

Comment: Oh BTW I got that view of the array from FireBug

Comment: Do you want to do this with PHP or JavaScript?  Please fix your tags accordingly.

Comment: well i dont know maybe JS cause i am going to use on D3 ?

Comment: before JSON Encode the array to Send it to JavaScript i preformed some kind of a function and returned the array like that:
`"\"Word\",\"Date\"\n\"#Tahrir\",\"2012-Oct-12\"\n\"#Tahrir\",\"2012-Oct-12\"\n\ `

Answer (score 0):

To convert json data to a CSV try using this http://jsfiddle.net/sturtevant/vUnF9/ (not my code)

```js
function JSON2CSV(objArray) {
var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

var str = '';
var line = '';

if ($("#labels").is(':checked')) {
    var head = array[0];
    if ($("#quote").is(':checked')) {
        for (var index in array[0]) {
            var value = index + "";
            line += '"' + value.replace(/"/g, '""') + '",';
        }
    } else {
        for (var index in array[0]) {
            line += index + ',';
        }
    }

    line = line.slice(0, -1);
    str += line + '\r\n';
}

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var line = '';

    if ($("#quote").is(':checked')) {
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            var value = array[i][index] + "";
            line += '"' + value.replace(/"/g, '""') + '",';
        }
    } else {
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            line += array[i][index] + ',';
        }
    }

    line = line.slice(0, -1);
    str += line + '\r\n';
}
return str;
}
```

Comment: Can you please re-upload your avatar to make it look better in the user card?

Comment: Cheers, much better now!